# Angular and SignalR throws 502

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I have used this great tutorial https://blog.sstorie.com/integrating-angular-2-and-signalr-part-2-of-2/ to implement a signalr client in angular. But if I want to connect from my website to my service hosted on Azure I get this error

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://...' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 
Unexpected response code: 502
```

My Azure APP has Websoket enabled and also cors in my service is set to *

My dependenciesin the package.json:

```
     "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "0.1.0",
    "admin-lte": "^2.3.11",
    "angular2-notifications": "^0.7.4",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "signalr": "^2.2.2",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "typescript": "2.3.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.52",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.0.6",
    "tslint": "^5.4.3",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  }
```

My angluar-cli.json contains this in the script section:

```
  "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalr.js",
        ...
      ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7" />` to my web.config the error disappear.